# how to create a table in SAP WEBI

Tags: business-objects

I have a table that I would like to be similar to something like this?

[image]

Appreciate the help on this thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're asking if header cells can be merged.  Yes, left-click on two cells to select them, then right-click and select "Merge" from the context menu.